# Returning a MutexGuard of a lazy_static Mutex from a function needs a lifetime parameter

Tags: rust

I'm writing tests using mock functions, controlling the return value among the tests with a `Mutex`:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate lazy_static;

#[cfg(test)]
pub use mock::*;
#[cfg(not(test))]
pub use real::*;

mod real {
    pub fn say_hello(_name: String) -> String {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}

/// simulate multiple uses, replace `real` in test.
mod mock {
    use std::sync::*;
    lazy_static! {
        pub static ref LOCK: Mutex<bool> = Mutex::new(true);
        pub static ref HELLO_VALUE: Mutex<String> = Mutex::new(String::default());
    }
    pub fn say_hello(_name: String) -> String {
        use std::ops::Deref;
        HELLO_VALUE.lock().unwrap().deref().clone()
    }

    pub fn set_hello_return_value(rtn: String) -> MutexGuard<bool> {
        let lock = LOCK.lock().unwrap();
        let mut value = HELLO_VALUE.lock().unwrap();
        *value = rtn;
        lock
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod test {
    use super::*;
    #[test]
    fn test1() {
        // repeated block begin--------------------------
        let _lock = LOCK.lock().unwrap();
        let mut value = HELLO_VALUE.lock().unwrap();
        *value = "Hello Tom!".to_string(); // just this line is different from test2
        drop(value);
        // repeat block end--------------------------
        assert_eq!("Hello Tom!", say_hello("".to_string()));
    }

    #[test]
    fn test2() {
        // repeated block begin--------------------------
        let _lock = LOCK.lock().unwrap();
        let mut value = HELLO_VALUE.lock().unwrap();
        *value = "Hello Jack!".to_string(); // just this line is different from test1
        drop(value);
        // repeat block end--------------------------
        assert_eq!("Hello Jack!", say_hello("".to_string()));
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_simplified_but_not_work() {
        let _lock = set_hello_return_value("Hello Mark!".to_string());
        assert_eq!("Hello Mark!", say_hello("".to_string()));
    }
}
```

You can see the **repeat block** that I want to simplify. I made a function `set_hello_return_value` but the compiler complained:

```
error[E0106]: missing lifetime specifier
  --> src/main.rs:28:51
   |
28 |     pub fn set_hello_return_value(rtn: String) -> MutexGuard<bool> {
   |                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected lifetime parameter
   |
   = help: this function's return type contains a borrowed value with an elided lifetime, but the lifetime cannot be derived from the arguments
   = help: consider giving it an explicit bounded or 'static lifetime
```

Please help me to correct it.

Comment: Why do you want to return a `MutexGuard` type?

Comment: to lock and avoid other tests to set values which may cause assert false

Comment: Please do not edit your *question* to include an *answer*. If you have something substantial to add, you are encouraged to post your own answer below, instead. However, the code you have is exactly the same as the answer that you accepted. Since you accepted it, that's already enough of a signal to everyone who reads this in the future. I've removed this from your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the complete error message:

> consider giving it an explicit bounded or 'static lifetime

Doing so works:

```
pub fn set_hello_return_value(rtn: String) -> MutexGuard<'static, bool> {
    let lock = LOCK.lock().unwrap();
    let mut value = HELLO_VALUE.lock().unwrap();
    *value = rtn;
    lock
}
```

---

I'd probably not return the guard at all, however:

```
pub fn with_hello_return_value<S, F>(rtn: S, f: F)
where
    S: Into<String>,
    F: FnOnce(),
{
    let _lock = LOCK.lock().unwrap();
    *HELLO_VALUE.lock().unwrap() = rtn.into();
    f()
}

#[test]
fn test_simplified() {
    with_hello_return_value("Hello Mark!", || {
        assert_eq!("Hello Mark!", say_hello("".to_string()));
    });
}
```

Honestly, I wouldn't do *any* of this as conditional compilation is overkill. If you need to test components of your system separately, *they shouldn't know about each other* to start with; they should be dependency-injected. This has the additional benefit that each test can inject its own value, preserving the multithreaded nature of the tests.

```
fn thing_that_uses_say_hello<G>(greeter: &G, name: &str) -> String
where
    G: Greeting,
{
    greeter.say_hello(name.into())
}

trait Greeting {
    fn say_hello(&self, name: &str) -> String;
}

struct RealGreeting;

impl Greeting for RealGreeting {
    fn say_hello(&self, name: &str) -> String {
        format!("Hello, {}", name)
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod test {
    use super::*;
    use std::cell::RefCell;

    struct MockGreeting<'a> {
        called_with: RefCell<Vec<String>>,
        value: &'a str,
    }

    impl<'a> MockGreeting<'a> {
        fn new(value: &'a str) -> Self {
            Self {
                value,
                called_with: Default::default(),
            }
        }
    }

    impl<'a> Greeting for MockGreeting<'a> {
        fn say_hello(&self, name: &str) -> String {
            self.called_with.borrow_mut().push(name.to_owned());
            self.value.to_owned()
        }
    }

    #[test]
    fn test1() {
        let g = MockGreeting::new("Hello");
        let r = thing_that_uses_say_hello(&g, "Tom");
        assert_eq!("Hello", r);
        assert_eq!(&*g.called_with.borrow(), &["Tom".to_string()]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Great, I learned a new grammar for lifetime. Thanks. 
By the way the tests run fine, but if I don't lock they will be failed.
And if it like you said, how to achieve my purpose.

Comment: My God! can you give me a piece of sample code to learn. I  come from java, my thoughts have lots of OO concepts

Comment: @llxxbb Java is completely filled with dependency injection; it's not a concept unique to Rust or even very new. I've added a sketch of what it could look like.

Comment: I got it. pass all you need by parameter, and mock the parameter that must be a `Trait`. I misunderstand the dependency-injection, all injection must be done manually not by some certain crate or other thing automatically. Thanks again.